# BroadcastReceiver with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service

I have **3 fragments inside a viewPager** currently. One of the fragments is to register a `BroadcastReceiver` but with the current implementation I am getting nothing at all.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getSherlockActivity().getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(
        broadcastReceiver,
        new IntentFilter(UpdateService.UPDATE_NOTIFICATION));
    optionsBroadcast = true;
}
```

where `optionsBroadcast` is a `boolean` value used to keep track of the service being called and `broadcastReceiver` is as follows:

```
public BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("onBroadcastReceiver", "service is being called ?");
        updateOptionsMenu(intent);
    }
};
```

I have also implemented the unRegister logic inside the `onPause` and `onResume`.

Now in the service class:

```
public class UpdateService extends Service{

    Intent updateIntent;
    public static final String UPDATE_NOTIFICATION =  "com.eps.support.updatenotification";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        updateIntent = new Intent(UPDATE_NOTIFICATION);
        new CheckUpdates().execute(getApplicationContext());
    }



    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.i("inside service", "onStartCommand");
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    public class CheckUpdates extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, String>{

        //URL parsing logic where either the setOnEqual() or setOnUpdate() is called.
    }

    public void setOnEqual(){
        updateIntent.putExtra("isUpdated", 1);
        sendBroadcast(updateIntent);

    }

    public void setOnUpdate(){
        updateIntent.putExtra("isUpdated", 2);
        sendBroadcast(updateIntent);
    }
}
```

I have also updated the manifest file pointing the class as a service. For some reason the service does not work. Or it does not do what it's supposed to do.setOnEqual()

Once we register for the service the service calls on the `AsyncTask` where either `setOnEqual()` or `setOnUpdate()` is called. With all the `Log` entries set up in the service, none of them is called.

Please help.

Comment: There are several parts which could possibly go wrong, you should add more Logs into your code (e.g. in your asynctask to check if it's being called, in setOnUpdate, in setOnEqual). However the BroadcastReceiver/Sender part looks fine to me.

Comment: Where do you bind/start your service ? On a side note, if your Service doesn't repeatedly execute Checkupdates, then i would highly suggest using an IntentService instead.

Comment: I start the service with my `sendBroadcast(intent)` don't I ?? And yes I don't have to repeatedly execute checkupdates ... I think i'll give `IntentService` a shot since nothings working. @Su-AuHwang thanks for the help.

Comment: no, sendBroadcast just sends a broadcast. To start the Service you'll have to either call bindService() or startService()